# Why is setting TransactionManager as JPATransactionManager in a Step not correct?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am working with Spring Batch and JPA and I experienced the TransactionManager bean conflict. I found a solution by setting the TransactionManager as JpaTransactionManager in a step. But according to this link (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/961), it is not correct even though it works for me.

```
@Autowired
private JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

private Step buildTaskletStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("SendCampaignStep")
                    .<UserAccount, UserAccount>chunk(pushServiceConfiguration.getCampaignBatchSize())
                    .reader(userAccountItemReader)
                    .processor(userAccountItemProcessor)
                    .writer(userAccountItemWriter)
                    .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                    .build();
    }
}
```

I tried the suggested solution of implementing the BatchConfigurer but it conflicts with me disabling the metadata tables using this code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist.
        // initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database)
    }

}
```

What would be the problem using the first solution of setting the TransactionManager in a Step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spring Batch, there are two places where a transaction manager is used:

- In the proxy created around the `JobRepository` to create transactional methods when interacting with the job repository
- In each step definition to drive the step's transaction

Typically, the same transaction manager is used in both places, but this is not a requirement. It is perfectly fine to use a `ResourcelessTransactionManager` with the job repository to not store any meta-data and a `JpaTransactionManager` in the step to persist data in a database.

By default, when you use `@EnableBatchProcessing` and you provide a `DataSource` bean, Spring Batch will create a `DataSourceTransactionManager` and set it in both places, because this is the most typical case. But nothing prevents you from using a different transaction manager for the step. In this case, you should accept that business data and technical meta-data can get out of sync when things go wrong.

That's why the expected way to provide a custom transaction manager is via a custom `BatchConfigurer#getTransactionManager`, in which case your custom transaction manager is set it in both places. This was not clearly documented, but it has been fixed since v4.1. Here is the section that mentions that: [Configuring a JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig). This is also mentioned in the Javadoc of [@EnableBatchProcessing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html):

```
In order to use a custom transaction manager, a custom BatchConfigurer should be provided.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify. If I don't care about the JobRepository, it is safe to specify the transaction manager for the business data in the step?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant in `It is perfectly fine to use a ResourcelessTransactionManager with the job repository to not store any meta-data and a JpaTransactionManager in the step to persist data in a database.`