# Role of PlatformTransactionManager with Spring batch 5

Tags: spring-batch

The documentation is not very clear about the role of `PlatformTransactionManager` in steps configuration.

First, `stepBuilder.tasklet` and `stepBuilder.chunk` requires a  `PlatformTransactionManager`  as second parameter while the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide) says *it is now required to manually configure the transaction manager on any tasklet step definition (...) This is only required for tasklet steps, other step types do not require a transaction manager by design.*.

More over, in the documentation the `transactionManager` is injected via a method parameter:

```
/**
 * Note the TransactionManager is typically autowired in and not needed to be explicitly
 * configured
 */
```

But the `transactionManager` created by Spring Boot is linked to the `DataSource` created by Spring Boot based on `spring.datasource.url`. So with autoconfiguration, the following beans works together: `dataSource`, `platformTransactionManager`, `jobRepository`. It makes sense for job and step executions metadata management.

But unless readers, writers and tasklet works with this default `DataSource` used by `JobOperator`, the auto configured `transactionManager` must not be used for the steps configuration. Am I right ?

Tasklets or a chunk oriented steps will often need another `PlatformTransactionManager`:

- if a step writes data in a specific db it needs a specific `DataSource` (not necessarily declared as bean otherwise the `JobRepository` will use it) and a specific `PlatformTransactionManager` linked to this `DataSource`
- if a step writes data in a file or send message to a MOM, the `ResourcelessTransactionManager` is more appropriate. This useful implementation is not mentioned in the documentation.

As far as I understand, the implementation of `PlatformTransactionManager` for a step depends on where the data are written and has nothing to do with the `transactionManager` bean used by the `JobOperator` Am I right ?

Example:

```java
var builder = new StepBuilder("step-1", jobRepository);
PlatformTransactionManager txManager = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
return builder.<Input, Output> chunk(10, txManager)
    .reader(reader())
    .processor(processor())
    .writer(writer()/*a FlatFileItemWriter*/)
    .build();
```

or

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    private DataSource dsForStep1Writer;
    
    public MyJobConfiguration(@Value("${ds.for.step1.writer.url"} String url) {
        this.dsForStep1Writer = new DriverManagerDataSource(url);
    }

    // reader() method, processor() method

    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Output> writer() {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Output>()
            .dataSource(this.dsForStep1Writer)
            .sql("...")
            .itemPreparedStatementSetter((item, ps)->{/*code*/})
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        var builder = new StepBuilder("step-1", jobRepository);
        var txManager = new JdbcTransactionManager(this.dsForStep1Writer);
        return builder.<Input, Output> chunk(10, txManager)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
    }
        // other methods
}
```

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

> Role of PlatformTransactionManager with Spring batch 5

The role of the transaction manager did ***not*** change between v4 and v5. I wrote [an answer about this a couple of years ago for v4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66119991/5019386), so I will update it for v5 here:

In Spring Batch, there are two places where a transaction manager is used:

- In the proxies created around the `JobRepository`/`JobExplorer` to create transactional methods when interacting with the job repository/explorer
- In each step definition to drive the step's transaction

Typically, the same transaction manager is used in both places, but this is not a requirement. It is perfectly fine to use a `ResourcelessTransactionManager` with the job repository to not store any meta-data and a `JpaTransactionManager` in the step to persist data in a database.

Now in v5, `@EnableBatchProcessing` does ***not*** register a transaction manager  bean in the application context anymore. You either need to manually configure one in the application context, or use the one auto-configured by Spring Boot (if you are a Spring Boot user).

What `@EnableBatchProcessing` will do though is look for a bean named `transactionManager` in the application context and set it on the auto-configured `JobRepository` and `JobExplorer` beans (this is configurable with the `transactionManagerRef` attribute). Again, this transaction manager bean could be manually configured or auto-configured by Boot.

Once that in place, it is up to you to set that transaction manager on your steps or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, yes there can be different transaction manager for the `JobOperator` (saving the job's state) and for the step itself (what you program).

If having problem that data changes on Spring-data repositories are not saved in the database, then the second transaction manager should be a `JpaTransactionManager`, as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65517607/7251133.